# Complex SQL where clause: many 'and' and 'or' conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a generated query to MS SQL Server with complex where clause like this:

```
(t1.Column1 = SomeValue1 and t1.Column2 = SomeValue2)
OR (t1.Column1 = SomeValue3 and t1.Column2 = SomeValue4)
OR (t1.Column1 = SomeValue5 and t1.Column2 = SomeValue6)
...
(50 or more conditions like this)
```

Actually I have hierarchy list with 3 level depth. And I want to retrieve all 3rd level items with one query. So t1.Column1 here is the 1st parent, t1.Column2 is the 2nd parent. I have as many conditions in my WHERE clause, as many items are expanded on the 2nd level in list. There can be 1000 or more in the worst case.

I wonder if this can affect query performance. If so, is there any way to optimize this(table-value parameters, etc.)?

I've done some investigations with query plans and query compile time. Both look ok.

Comment: There can't be definite answer for this. There are too many variables, like indexes, etc. You didn't provide enough info to even judge it well. And, if you have 1000 conditions, something must be wrong with your entire design

Comment: Are t1.Column1 and t1.Column2 always the same two columns, and are they indexed?

Comment: @pm_2 Yes. Both have indexes.

Comment: If both columns are always requested together they should be together in one index.

Comment: Are the SomeValue values bind variables, or are they simply hard coded values?

Comment: Actually I have variables. But as I generate query myself, I can do any way. I just wonder if such queries are OK for SQL SERVER and what are the best way to query data with such filters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and answer; this answer will not be correct, because there isn't really a 'correct' answer given your level of detail.  However, here's some possible tips (assuming that you NEED 1000 clauses in your query):

- Try to keep the query consistent once created and executed.  It will probably take some time to compile, but once compiled, the cache should do its job, unless you keep changing it (even if you just change the values around).  Use bind variables if the values need to change.
- Indexes - make sure both columns are indexed.  Providing they both are and you always query both then you should be fine.

As a caveat to this - I'm not saying this is a good way to query a database, just that the two points above should help.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to get help with full query. Just want to be sure that many conditions in WHERE clause is an extensible thing. And I won't get great performance decrease when the count of conditions got bigger.

Comment: Compile time will probably increase; however, if you manage the values properly that should be a one-off